# GRASS mapcalc in Python Shell

Tags: python, grass-gis

I'm trying to convert my GRASS/Bash script into the Phython Shell. Now I have a raster dataset (test.01) which I want to convert in `1` or `0`. In GRASS I used the command [`r.mapcalc`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.mapcalc.html)

```bash
r.mapcalc test.new.01="if(test.01/test==1,1,0)"
```

Now in the Python Shell I figured just the first steps, but I don't get the concept how to return the calculation into a new raster dataset.

```py
import grass.script as grass
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
for rast in grass.list_strings(type = 'rast'):
    print rast
...
...
test.01@mapset
```

Now I tried to use the Python function [`grass.raster.mapcalc()`](https://grass.osgeo.org/programming6/namespacepython_1_1raster.html#a80d619f8519e5be67d4ff52c0c3fdf04) but without success, it kills my GRASS GIS process.

```py
expr = "if(test.01@mapset/test.01@mapset==1,1,0)"
output = grass.raster.mapcalc(expr)
```

The question is also how to write the result into a new raster dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the raster map algebra: any expression needs and input raster and a resulting raster and this layer is automatically added to the mapset.

In [grass.raster.mapcalc()](https://grass.osgeo.org/programming6/namespacepython_1_1raster.html#a80d619f8519e5be67d4ff52c0c3fdf04) , the example is

```
expr1 = '"%s" = "%s" * 10' % (output_raster, input_raster)
```

If I define the input and output rasters as:

```
input_raster = "test.01@mapset"
output_raster = "test.02@mapset"
```

The expression is

```
expr1 = '"%s" = "%s" * 10' % (output, input)
print expr1
"test.02@mapset" = "test.01@mapset" * 10
```

In your expression `expr = "if(test.01@mapset/test.01@mapset==1,1,0)"` there is no resulting raster.

```
 expr = "if(test.01@mapset/test.01@mapset==1,1,0)"
 print expr
 if(test.01@mapset/test.01@mapset==1,1,0)
```

The expression you want is:

- if the value of `test.01@mapset/test.01@mapset = 1` is true (cell by cell) then the value of the cell in test.02@mapset is 1
- if the value of `test.01@mapset/test.01@mapset = 1` is false (cell by cell) then the value of the cell in test.02@mapset is 0

The correct solution would be

```
"test.02@mapset" = "if(test.01@mapset/test.01@mapset==1,1,0)"
# or
"test.02@mapset = if(test.01@mapset/test.01@mapset==1,1,0)"
```

But the result of your expression will always give 1 because,cell value by cell value, test.01@mapset/test.01@mapset = 1

Comment: some how it wants me to set quotation marks around the rasterdata name.  `expr1 = '"%s" = if("%s"/"%s"==1,1,0)' % (output, input, input)` or `"test.02@mapset" = if("test.01@mapset"/"test.01@mapset"==1,1,0)`.

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://github.com/wenzeslaus/python-grass-addon - shortcourse on Python in GRASS GIS as an ipython notebook (scroll down to see how to launch the course)